# HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator is not found in Axis2

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, axis, basic-authentication

Just generated Java code from WSDL using **Apache Axis 2**. The service is protected with basic authentication. When I try to create authentication object in order to set the username and password, the class (`HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator`) is not found in the library.

How can I set basic authentication for the client code generated by **Apache Axis2**?

Here is the ***old way*** of setting basic authentication params:

```
HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator basicAuth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
basicAuth.setUsername("username");
basicAuth.setPassword("password");
basicAuth.setPreemptiveAuthentication(true);

final Options clientOptions = stub._getServiceClient().getOptions();
clientOptions.setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, basicAuth);
stub._getServiceClient().setOptions(clientOptions);
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same Problem!

Solution: Use `HttpTransportPropertiesImpl` instead of `HttpTransportProperties`.

Comment: The class doesn't exist in newer versions, and I can't find anything in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

```
    org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient _operationClient = _serviceClient.createClient(_operations[1].getName());
    _operationClient.getOptions()
            .setAction("http://asdf/checkOutRequest");

    HttpTransportPropertiesImpl.Authenticator basicAuth = new HttpTransportPropertiesImpl.Authenticator();
    basicAuth.setUsername("tomcat");
    basicAuth.setPassword("tomcat");
    basicAuth.setPreemptiveAuthentication(true);

    final Options clientOptions = _operationClient.getOptions();
    clientOptions.setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, basicAuth);
    _operationClient.setOptions(clientOptions);
```

For anybody needing a even more explicit example of uwesch's very helpful answer.